# MySQL group by date and count including missing dates

Tags: mysql, date, mysql5

Previously I was doing following to get per day count from reports table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, tracked_on
 FROM `reports`
 WHERE (domain_id = 939 AND tracked_on >= '2014-01-01' AND tracked_on <= '2014-12-31')
 GROUP BY tracked_on
 ORDER BY tracked_on ASC;
```

Obviously this wont give me 0 count for missing dates.

Then I finally found a [optimum solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2157776/1125893) to generate date-series between given date range.
But the next challenge am facing is to join it with my reports table and get the count grouped by date.

```
select count(*), all_dates.Date as the_date, domain_id
from (
    select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) all_dates
inner JOIN reports r
    on all_dates.Date >= '2014-01-01'
  and all_dates.Date <= '2014-12-31'
where all_dates.Date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31' AND domain_id = 939 GROUP BY the_date order by the_date ASC ;
```

The result am getting is

```
count(*)    the_date    domain_id
46  2014-01-01  939
46  2014-01-02  939
46  2014-01-03  939
46  2014-01-04  939
46  2014-01-05  939
46  2014-01-06  939
46  2014-01-07  939
46  2014-01-08  939
46  2014-01-09  939
46  2014-01-10  939
46  2014-01-11  939
46  2014-01-12  939
46  2014-01-13  939
46  2014-01-14  939
...
```

---

Whereas am looking to fill in the missing dates with 0

*something like*

```
count(*)    the_date    domain_id
12  2014-01-01  939
23  2014-01-02  939
46  2014-01-03  939
0   2014-01-04  939
0   2014-01-05  939
99  2014-01-06  939
1   2014-01-07  939
5   2014-01-08  939
...
```

---

Another try that I gave was:

```
select count(*), all_dates.Date as the_date, domain_id
from (
    select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) all_dates
inner JOIN reports r
    on all_dates.Date = r.tracked_on
where all_dates.Date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31' AND domain_id = 939 GROUP BY the_date order by the_date ASC ;
```

Results:

```
count(*)    the_date    domain_id
38        2014-09-03     939
8         2014-09-04     939
```

Minimal data with above queries: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dee3e/6

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Sure, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dee3e/6
here's the minimal table with rows.

Comment: It's just a suggestion, you don't have to follow it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an `OUTER JOIN` to arrive at every day between a start and an end because if you use an `INNER JOIN` it will restrict the output to just the dates that are joined (i.e. just those dates in the report table).

In addition, when you use an `OUTER JOIN` you must take care that conditions in the `where clause` don't cause an `implicit inner join`; for example **AND domain_id = 1** if use in the where clause would suppress any row that did not have that condition met, but when used as a join condition it only restricts the rows of the report table.

```
SELECT
      COUNT(r.domain_id)
    , all_dates.Date AS the_date
    , domain_id
FROM (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) ) DAY as Date
        FROM (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
        CROSS JOIN (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
      ) all_dates
      LEFT OUTER JOIN reports r
                  ON all_dates.Date = r.tracked_on
                        AND domain_id = 1
WHERE all_dates.Date BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-30'
GROUP BY
      the_date
ORDER BY
      the_date ASC;
```

I have also changed the all_dates derived table, by using `DATE_ADD()` to push the starting point into the future, and I have reduced the it's size. Both of these are options and can be tweaked as you see fit.

<kbd>[Demo at SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b282/1)</kbd>

---

to arrive at a domain_id for every row (as shown in your question) you would need to use someting like the following; Note you could use `IFNULL()` which is MySQL specific but I have used `COALESCE()` which is more generic SQL. However use of an @parameter as shown here is MySQL specific anyway.

```
SET @domain := 1;

SELECT
      COUNT(r.domain_id)
    , all_dates.Date AS the_date
    , coalesce(domain_id,@domain) AS domain_id
FROM (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 month) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) ) DAY as Date
        FROM (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
        CROSS JOIN (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
      ) all_dates
      LEFT JOIN reports r
                  ON all_dates.Date = r.tracked_on
                        AND domain_id = @domain
WHERE all_dates.Date BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-30'
GROUP BY
      the_date
ORDER BY
      the_date ASC;
```

<kbd>[See this at SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b282/3)</kbd>

Comment: Awesome! that just worked :)
Would it be possible to have a set of days grouped by weeks and months also ? Similar to what we have of all 'days' can I have all weeks in a   year.

Comment: So pleased it was your answer - please take one second to click the tick mark - this indicates that the answer has been accepted. It is possible to work with larger time units like week, month, year but for these we typically use date ranges (from/to date pairs).

Answer (score 1):

The `all_dates` subquery is only looking back from the current day (`curdate()`). If you want to include future dates, change the first line of the subquery to something like:

```
select '2015-01-01' - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
```