# How does mysql return the number of clicks saved in the table by dates range?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1 click log table as follows:

| id | adname | ctimes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 2023-10-11 10:20:53 |
| 2 | abc | 2023-10-11 10:21:53 |
| 3 | abc | 2023-10-11 10:22:53 |
| 4 | abc | 2023-10-12 10:20:53 |
| 5 | abc | 2023-10-15 10:20:53 |
| 6 | abc | 2023-10-15 10:21:53 |
| 7 | cde | 2023-10-11 10:20:53 |

my results:

| date | name | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-11 | abc | 3 |
| 2023-10-12 | abc | 1 |
| 2023-10-15 | abc | 2 |

i hope results:

| date | name | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-10 | abc | 0 |
| 2023-10-11 | abc | 3 |
| 2023-10-12 | abc | 1 |
| 2023-10-13 | abc | 0 |
| 2023-10-14 | abc | 0 |
| 2023-10-15 | abc | 2 |

The results returned include only those records with the results. How do I get the full date range with zero if there is no record?
Hope to hear from you. Thank you!!!

My php code:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$defaultdateto = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date."+1 day")));
$defaultdateat = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date."-7 day")));
$period = new DatePeriod($startdate, new DateInterval('P1D'), $enddate);

foreach ($period as $date) {
    $dates[] = $date->format("Y-m-d");
}

function loaddata($ads) {
    $sql = '';
    foreach($GLOBALS['dates'] as $ngay) {
        
        $query_parts[] = "(SELECT
        Count(logclick.id) AS vcount, date( logclick.ctimes ) AS vdate,
    logclick.adname
    FROM 
    logclick
    WHERE ctimes BETWEEN '".$ngay."' AND DATE_ADD('".$ngay."',INTERVAL 1 DAY) and adname = '".$ads."'
    GROUP BY
    logclick.adname,
    date( logclick.ctimes )
    ORDER BY
    vcount DESC)";
    }
    $sql .= implode(' UNION ALL ', $query_parts);  
    //  die($sql);
      $query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'], $sql);
    $result = array();
      if ($query && mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
      
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      {
          array_push($result, $row); 
      }
      mysqli_free_result($query);
    }
    return $result;
    }

$fulllist = loaddata("abc");

// return list click by date
```

Comment: Does this have to be finished with sql? You can fill in the missing dates yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The logs are automatic and I don't know how to produce results automatically without inserting more records manually

Comment: One common solution to this kind of thing is to left-join to a "calendar" table which contains all possible dates. You can search for examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+missing+dates+after+group+by)

Comment: I mean manually fill in `$result` with missing dates.

Comment: Why are you building that UNION of "per day" queries, instead of just passing in the start and end datetimes?

Comment: Thank @ADyson your keywords help me found solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804531/mysql-group-by-date-and-count-including-missing-dates